# There exists $e_1,...,e_r\in E $ and $v_1,...,v_{n-2r} \in \ker (u)$ such that $\{e_1,u (e_1),...,e_r,u (e_r),v_1,...,v_{n-2r}\} $ is basis of $E$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $n\geq 3$ and $E$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C} $

$u $ be an endomorphism of $E $ nilpotent with index $2 $ $(u\circ u=0)$ and $\operatorname{Rank}(u) =r$ we suppose that $\operatorname{im} (u)\subsetneq \ker (u) $.

**Problem**

Show that there exists $e_1,...,e_r\in E $ and $v_1,...,v_{n-2r} \in \ker (u)$ such that $\{e_1,u (e_1),...,e_r,u (e_r),v_1,...,v_{n-2r}\} $ is basis of $E $.

**My effort**:

Let $\{f_1,...,f_r\} $ be a basis of $\operatorname{im}(u) $ then for all $i $ there exists $e_i $ such that $f_i=u (e_i).$

$\{e_1,u (e_1),...,e_r,u (e_r)\}$ be a set of vectors which is linearly independent because
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{r}{\lambda_ie_i}+\sum_{i=1}^{r}{\lambda_i^{'}u(e_i)}=0\Rightarrow u (\sum_{i=1}^{r}{\lambda_ie_i}+\sum_{i=1}^{r}{\lambda_i^{'}u(e_i)})=0
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{r}{\lambda_iu (e_i)}=0\Rightarrow \lambda _i=0\qquad \forall i
$$
then $\lambda^{'}_i=0,\forall i$.
But Ii can't to show the existence of $v_1,...,v_{n-2r} \in \ker (u)$ such that $\{e_1,u (e_1),...,e_r,u (e_r),v_1,...,v_{n-2r}\} $ is linearly independent.

An idea please.

Comment: $f_1,\dots,f_r\in\ker u$ are linearly independent, right? Now extend to a basis for $\ker u$. What is left to show?

Comment: @Ted see the edit please

Comment: I don't see anything significant. Have you answered my question?

Comment: ok thanks it's a good idea